# Linux Serial disable DTR PHP

Tags: php, linux, arduino, serial-port

I'm trying to work with an Arduino on Linux with PHP
I have a working script, but the ([DTR option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Terminal_Ready) is enabled. This let the Arduino restart on open the connection, so the question is how to disable DTR.

I have run this once

```
stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 cs8 9600 ignbrk -brkint -imaxbel -opost -onlcr -isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke noflsh -ixon -crtscts
```

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$fp =fopen("/dev/ttyACM0", "w+");
if( !$fp) {
        echo "Error";die("can't open Serialport!");
}
sleep(2);// wait while restart
fwrite($fp, "1");// turn LED on
$s = null;
while($s != "0"){// wait for answer
        $s = fread($fp, 1);
}
echo $s."<- relsult";
fclose($fp);
?>
```

This is the Arduino code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {
  if ( Serial.available() > 0 ) {
    int inByte = Serial.read(); 
    if (inByte == 0x30) {digitalWrite(13, HIGH);}
    if (inByte == 0x31) {digitalWrite(13, LOW);}
    delay(50);//psydo for doing other things
    Serial.print("0");//say i am ready for the next
  }
}
```

Have any one an idea to disable the DTR option.

Comment: Did you try one of these methods: http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DisablingAutoResetOnSerialConnection?

Comment: @Artium I have no access to the Hardware, and the Software example is for Python not PHP

Comment: @FabianHarmsen Did you have any success in disabling DTR? I tried `hupcl` but it didn't work. Do you also use [`serialport`](https://github.com/lepiaf/serialport/issues/3) php library by `lepiaf`?

Comment: @DRSDavidSoft i know i found an way to work with the arduino, but after more than 2 year i forget how and i dont have access to this code anymore. I don't used any kind of libary